Encountering CORS Errors When Calling Flask Sending File API from Browser, But It Works in Postman
I am developing a Flask application and have implemented CORS support.
Everything works fine when I test my API using Postman.
However, when I attempt to make requests via a browser, I encounter CORS errors.
The API URL is under a certified Google domain, and CORS settings are supposedly configured correctly both in the application and for the API.
Below is a simplified version of my code
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/runExcel', methods=['POST'])
def run_backtest_excel():
    output = BytesIO()
    request_data = request.get_json()

    # Handling of data logic here...

    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        data.to_excel(writer, index=True, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    output.seek(0)

    response = send_file(output, download_name="data_detail.xlsx", as_attachment=True, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization'
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=4000)

frontend React Code
const exportFile = async() => {
    try{
      const result = StrategyExcelFetcher("example.com/runExcel", backtestFormBody)
      console.log(backtestFormBody)
    } catch {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

Output from browser:
enter image description here
I thought it was an nginx or domain issue so I tried calling directly from my backend IP,
didnt work too.
So does adding CORS to my nginx settings.
All other API calls from the same app/backend works just fine wether it's from postman or browser frontend.

You need preflight OPTIONS request handling

Does this answer your question? XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

See also Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?
